# Decode QR code from Byte[] using ZXing in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zxing

I can decode QR code from an image file as follows-

```
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imagePath);
 BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
 Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
 decodedData = result.Text;
```

But I want it to do from Byte[].

```
 Byte[] imagefile;
 using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["files"].InputStream))
 {
      imagefile = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength);//image
 }
```

I would like to read QR code from this imagefile variable. Is there any way to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["files"].InputStream))
{
    byte[] imagefile = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength); //image
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(imagefile))
    using (Image bitmap = Image.FromStream(memory)
    {
        BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
        decodedData = result.Text;
    }
}
```

Or may be even shorter:

```
using (Image bitmap = Image.FromStream(Request.Files["files"].InputStream))
{
    BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
    Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
    decodedData = result.Text;
}
```

Comment: @SKPaul You can cast `Image` to `Bitmap`, like `reader.Decode((Bitmap)bitmap);`.